# Current Opinion journal format with Biblatex

Tags: biblatex

I'm trying to achieve this citation style with biblatex.

[image]

The reference numbers should be listed in order and in square brackets [] in the text. There should be no more than 10 authors displayed.

Could someone help me achieve this with minimal code?

Comment: If you need this for submission to the publisher, please note that it is possible that the publisher cannot accept `biblatex` submissions (if they only ever want a PDF you are probably fine, but if they at some point request also the `.tex` source chances are `biblatex` might not be acceptable). `biblatex` requires a very different workflow from traditional BibTeX and may not be compatible with the processing steps the publisher applies to the manuscript. ...

Comment: ... Many publishers that accept TeX submissions have TeX templates or at least TeX submission guidelines that tell you how to prepare your TeX manuscript. Unless the template explicitly uses `biblatex` or the guidelines explicitly recommend it, I would probably stick with standard BibTeX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a couple of exceptions, most of your needs can be met using the configuration options of the standard `biblatex` styles along with some extensions provided by `biblatex-ext`.

Your question is very broad and often won't get an answer here. In future please provide a [MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography) with what you have tried and aim to ask one specific thing per question.

Compile with `lualatex` for ease of font support:

```
% TeX Program = lualatex

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[default]{sourcesanspro}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@article{alba+etal:1999,
  author = {de Alba, Eva and Santoro, Jorge and Rico, Manuel and Jiménez, M. Angeles},
  title = {\mkbibemph{De novo} Design of a Monomeric Three-stranded Anti-parallel β-sheet},
  sorttitle = {De novo Design of a Monomeric Three-stranded Anti-parallel β-sheet},
  journaltitle = {Protein Sci},
  date = {1999},
  volume = {8},
  pages = {854-865}
}
@collection{archer+barber:2004,
  editor = {Archer, Mary D. and Barber, James},
  title = {Molecular to Global Photosynthesis},
  publisher = {Imperial College Press},
  date = {2004}
}
@incollection{in:archer+barber:2004,
  author = {Archer, Mary D. and Barber, James},
  title = {Photosynthesis and Photoconversion},
  pages = {1-41},
  crossref = {archer+barber:2004}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[
    articlein=false,
    giveninits,
    maxnames=10,
    sorting=none,
    style=ext-numeric,
    useprefix,
  ]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{
  byeditor = {edited by},
  editor   = {ed},
  editors  = {eds},
}

\renewcommand*{\bibinitdelim}{}
\renewcommand*{\bibinitperiod}{}
\renewcommand*{\bibpagespunct}{\addcolon}
\renewcommand*{\intitlepunct}{\addspace}
\renewcommand*{\jourvoldelim}{\addcomma\space}
\renewcommand*{\pubdatedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}
\renewcommand*{\revsdnamepunct}{\addspace}
\renewcommand*{\volnumdelim}{\addcolon}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib,biblist]{editortypedelim}{\addspace}
\DeclareDelimFormat[bib,biblist]{nametitledelim}{\addcolon\space}

\DeclareDelimAlias[bib,biblist]{finalnamedelim}[]{multinamedelim}

\DeclareFieldFormat{editortype}{\bibsentence\mkbibparens{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{issuedate}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article, incollection]{titlecase}{\MakeSentenceCase*{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{titlecase:booktitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{titlecase:journaltitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,incollection]{title}{\mkbibbold{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{volume}{\mkbibbold{#1}}

\DeclareNameAlias{default}{family-given}

% reorder date in article
\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
  \usebibmacro{journal}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{issue+date}%
  \setunit*{\jourvoldelim}%
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\setunit*{\jourserdelim}%
     \printfield{series}%
     \setunit{\servoldelim}}%
  \usebibmacro{volume+number+eid}%
  \setunit{\addcolon\space}%
  \usebibmacro{issue}%
  \newunit}

% lowercase prefix
\renewbibmacro*{begentry}{\midsentence}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum \autocite{alba+etal:1999}.
Lorem ipsum \autocite{archer+barber:2004}.
Lorem ipsum \autocite{in:archer+barber:2004}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: The `\DeclareFieldFormat{titlecase}` could be simplified by using the optional argument instead of `\ifentrytype`: `\DeclareFieldFormat[article,incollection,inbook]{titlecase:title}{\MakeSentenceCase*{#1}}`.